# Using Boost Graph Library (BGL) to identify connected components

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am trying to use the Boost Ggraph Library. On each iteration of my program, I have a set of points, e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} on iteration one and {1,2,3,...,1000} on iteration two, ...

For each point I know which other points it is connected to, e.g. at iteration one every point is connected as below:

```
c(1)={3,5,7,8}   
c(2)={}   
c(3)={1,4,10}   
c(4)={3}    
c(5)={1,9}   
c(6)={}    
c(7)={1,8}    
c(8)={1,7}    
c(9)={5}    
c(10)={3}
```

Each point has a property, e.g. p(1)=10, p(2)=100, p(3)=20, ...

How can I create an undirected graph in Boost and iterate over the connected component(s)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to include the following headers:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
```

Then you need to declare a type for your graph. The following is suitable for the requirements you gave, however you might want to consult [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) to learn more about other choices for template parameters:

```
typedef
  boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS            // edge list
  , boost::vecS            // vertex list
  , boost::undirectedS     // directedness
  , float                  // property associated with vertices
  >
Graph;
```

You may create a graph with a given number of points, and you may later add more points:

```
Graph c (10);              // create a graph with 10 points
boost::add_vertex (c);     // add a vertex to the graph
```

To add edges use (note that vertices are enumerated starting from 0):

```
boost::add_edge (0, 1, c); // add an edge between vertices 0 and 1 in the graph
```

Finally, with the following piece of code you may compute connected components in your graph:

```
std::vector<int> component (boost::num_vertices (c));
size_t num_components = boost::connected_components (c, &component[0]);
```

The value returned from the function is the number of found components. Each item in `component` vector will be set to the component id of the corresponding vertex. This means that you can iterate over it and e.g. print the vertices that belong to a particular component:

```
std::cout << "Vertices in the first component:" << std::endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < boost::num_vertices (c); ++i)
  if (component[i] == 0)
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: Thanks @taketwo. In case, I would have several sub-graphs in this collection, does boost also give me number of available sub-graphs? can I iterate through my sub-graphs with this.

Comment: Yes, boost returns the number of components found (as one might expect, it is stored in `num_components` in the second last snippet). Also, the very last snippet shows how to iterate though vertices of a particular component (i.e. subgraph). You may add another loop around it to iterate though all components. Another option is to look at [boost-subgraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html).

BTW, if your original question is answered, please accept the answer.

Comment: This is not correct, for example if vertex with vertex descriptor 0 was deleted from the graph, the graph consists of vertex descriptors 1, 2, ..., boost::num_vertices(c). 

You need to keep track of the vertex descriptors of these vertices, it is not safe to assume that vertex descriptors at any given time are simply 0 -> num_vertices()-1.

Comment: I suppose what you mean is that `std::cout << i << " ";` does not give us vertex descriptors, but rather sequential indices into the vector of vertices of the graph? Please suggest a fix, I will be happy to update the last snippet.